# I'm having an issue with deploying angular app to github pages

Tags: angular, github

The website functions fine in Firefox but when looked at in chrome I get the following error messages

```
styles.7c3fd40….css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
runtime.2620947….js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
polyfills.bebee6a….js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
main.700130d….js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
%3Cultan-kearns%3E.g…earns/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

sorry if this is a stupid question I haven't used github pages with angular much.

The site in question is: https://ultan-kearns.github.io/ultankearns/

I have tried to run the site in Opera and Edge and I get the same errors and also I have tried redeploying the site multiple times and I am fairly stuck. Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `base href` in `index.html` file :

```
<base href="https://<ultan-kearns>.github.io/ultankearns/">
```

it should be this :

```
<base href="https://ultan-kearns.github.io/ultankearns/">
```

---

**This code block should be inside your head tag,**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Your html file looks out, it should be formatted/look like this :

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Website</title>
        <base href="https://ultan-kearns.github.io/ultankearns/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.7c3fd40d0bab5f41ea0e.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bebee6a5ef0ece001bc6.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.700130d31064f7530e56.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **Please compare this with your `index.html` and replace this with yours
>   and upload it on gitgub it will work.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had that in the file already still doesn't work with chrome at all.

Comment: @UltanKearns, file doesn't seems to be changed, open this in chrome `view-source:https://ultan-kearns.github.io/ultankearns/` and check again

Comment: @UltanKearns, please check https://vivekdoshi2.github.io/ultankearns/ , I have uploaded the same code and its working for me. you can check the code https://github.com/vivekdoshi2/ultankearns

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had an error in the files everything is working now, I had some stuff in my index.html that shouldn't have been there.